# html (with css) to pdf conversion in java script

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest a good (preferably free or inexpensive) java script library that can convert HTML (with css links) to PDF?  Right now i am using flying java library.  But the problem is when we switched over to https it fails to process the css files and doesnt work.  Also every time I need to generate a pdf i need to do it on the server side.  So a java script library (or any other client side scripting language) would be ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: I will be quite surprised if there is such a thing. For the money (that is, $0), FlyingSaucer is by far the best such solution I've seen. In my experience its CSS support is amazing, and frankly I can't understand what switching to "https" could possibly have to do with FlyingSaucer invocation.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's very experimental and it doesn't work in every browser, here you may find a solution:

http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/

Comment: That looks pretty interesting, but it's a far cry from the facilities FlyingSaucer was providing to @hese. The FlyingSaucer tools convert XHTML with CSS (incl. some important print enhancements from CSS3) to PDF, and it's got a very powerful and capable layout engine.